# plotting a line graph on a count plot with a separate y-axis on the right side

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I've created a dummy dataframe which is similar to the one I'm using. 
The dataframe consists of Fare prices, Cabin-type, and Survival (1 is alive, 0 = dead).

The first plot creates many graphs via factorplot, with each graph representing the Cabin type. The x-axis is represented by the Fare price and Y-axis is just a count of the number of occurrences at that Fare price.

What I then did was created another series, via groupby of [Cabin, Fare] and then proceeded to take the mean of the survival to get the survival rate at each Cabin and Fare price.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns


df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        Fare=[20, 10, 30, 40, 40, 10, 20, 30, 40 ,30, 20, 30, 30],
        Cabin=list('AAABCDBDCDDDC'),
        Survived=[1, 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,1 ,1 ,0 ,1 ,1 , 0, 1, 1]
    ))

g =sns.factorplot(x='Fare', col='Cabin', kind='count', data=df,
                  col_wrap=3, size=3, aspect=1.3,  palette='muted')

plt.show()
```

[image]

```
x =df.groupby(['Cabin','Fare']).Survived.mean()
```

What I would like to do is, plot an lineplot on the count graph above, (so the x-axis is the same, and each graph is still represented by a Cabin-type), but I would like the y-axis to be the survival mean we calculated with the groupby series x in the code above, which when outputted would be the third column below.

```
Cabin  Fare
A      10      0.000000
       20      1.000000
       30      0.000000
B      20      1.000000
       40      0.000000
C      30      1.000000
       40      0.500000
D      10      1.000000
       20      0.000000
       30      0.666667
```

The y-axis for the line plot should be on the right side, and the range I would like is [0, .20, .40, .60, .80, 1.0, 1.2]

I looked through the seaborn docs for a while, but I couldn't figure out how to properly do this.

My desired output looks something like this image. I'm sorry my writing looks horrible, I don't know how to use paint well. So the ticks and numbers are on the right side of each graph. The line plot will be connected via dots at each x,y point. So for Cabin A, the first x,y point is (10,0) with 0 corresponding to the right y-axis. The second point is (20,1) and so on. [image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you want this to look like.  Can you draw on the image where you think the lines ought to be?

Comment: Hi piRSquared. Is there a way to draw on the graph via the tools on this site? Or do I need to use MS paint? I will have to play around with MS paint as I'm not too familiar with it.

Comment: Okay, I played around with MS paint and added my desired output. I hope my additions are clear.

Comment: that's perfect. I'll get to look at it later. Unless someone else beats me to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Data operations:***

Compute frequency counts:

```
df_counts = pd.crosstab(df['Fare'], df['Cabin'])
```

[image]

Compute means across the group and unstack it back to obtain a `DF`. The `Nan's` are left as they are and not replaced by zero's to show the break in the line plot or else they would be continuous which wouldn't make much sense here.

```
df_means = df.groupby(['Cabin','Fare']).Survived.mean().unstack().T
```

[image]

Prepare the x-axis labels as strings:

```
df_counts.index = df_counts.index.astype(str)
df_means.index = df_means.index.astype(str)
```

***Plotting:***

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 4, figsize=(10,4))
df_counts.plot.bar(ax=ax, ylim=(0,5), cmap=plt.cm.Spectral, subplots=True,               
                   legend=None, rot=0)
# Use secondary y-axis(right side)
df_means.plot(ax=ax, secondary_y=True, marker='o', color='r', subplots=True, 
              legend=None, xlim=(0,4))
# Adjust spacing between subplots
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.5, hspace=0.5)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I can't take a deep look at your answer at the moment, but it looks good at first glance.

Comment: Hi, I'm just getting around to looking more deeply at the code.
I curious about this step` "Prepare the x-axis labels as strings"`.
Is it always recommended to convert the labels into strings, (even though in this case, I'm using numbers as the values for x)?

Comment: For this particular case when I was plotting, the `xticks` turned out to be the default integer index axis (0,1,2...) which ruined the complete plot even though the index had been originally (10,20,...). Seems it was picking up the default index values for whatever reason being. So, as a workaround, the dtype of index axis was converted to `str` and voila it worked then.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @NickilMaveli Thanks for the `xticks` explanation, ran into it while plotting something similar!